# Data wrangling - calculate average of certain rows in a variable based on other column's information

Tags: r, average

I want to calculate the average of certain rows in a column based on another variable. `dfin` is the original df. I want to create a df like `dfout`

```
dfin <- data.frame(c1 = c("a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a3","a3","a3","a3","a3","a3"),
                 c2 = c("b1","b1","b2","b2","b3","b3","b4","b4","b5","b5","b6","b6","b7","b7","b8","b8","b9","b9"),
                 c3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18))

dfout <- data.frame(c1 = c("a1","a1","a1","a2","a2","a2","a3","a3","a3"),
                 c2 = c("b1","b2","b3","b4","b5","b6","b7","b8","b9"),
                 c3 = c(1.5,3.5,5.5,7.5,9.5,11.5,13.5,15.5,17.5))
```

I want to calculate the average of rows in c3 based on c2 information. `dfin` has three columns `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`

c1 has `a1, a2, a3`, c2 has `b1, b2, b3, to b9`, and `c3` comprises values.

As can be seen in `dfout`, I want to create a new df that has calculated average of values in c3 based on c2 groups. Also keeping c1 information.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of variable `c1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dfin <- data.frame(c1 = c("a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a3","a3","a3","a3","a3","a3"),
                   c2 = c("b1","b1","b2","b2","b3","b3","b4","b4","b5","b5","b6","b6","b7","b7","b8","b8","b9","b9"),
                   c3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18))

dfin %>% 
  group_by(c1, c2) %>% 
  summarise(c3 = mean(c3), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   c1    c2       c3
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a1    b1      1.5
#> 2 a1    b2      3.5
#> 3 a1    b3      5.5
#> 4 a2    b4      7.5
#> 5 a2    b5      9.5
#> 6 a2    b6     11.5
#> 7 a3    b7     13.5
#> 8 a3    b8     15.5
#> 9 a3    b9     17.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>